# Checking if tweet contains a link to external site

Tags: twitter

To check if a tweet contains a link to an external site, I'm just checking that the tweet contains 'http:' ? Will this suffice ?

I'm accessing the tweets using the twitter rest API, so I parse the json response which contains the tweets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the URLs of a tweet using [Twitter Entities](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities). When you make the REST call, make sure you include

```
&include_entities=true
```

This will give you a section in the JSON or XML called entities. There will be a child node called urls.

Here's an example of what will be returned.

```
"text": "Twitter for Mac is now easier and faster, and you can open multiple windows at once http://t.co/0JG5Mcq",

    "entities": {

      "media": [

      ],

      "urls": [

        {

          "url": "http://t.co/0JG5Mcq",

          "display_url": "blog.twitter.com/2011/05/twitte…",

          "expanded_url": "http://blog.twitter.com/2011/05/twitter-for-mac-update.html",

          "indices": [

            84,

            103

          ]

        }

      ],

      "user_mentions": [

      ],

      "hashtags": [

      ]

    }
```

So, look for entities -> urls to see if a tweet contains a link to an external site.

Answer (score 1):

How do you access the tweets? By scraping the twitter site, or through some API? If you use an API, which one, etc.  It looks to me like the `js-tweet-text` section of the source is always formatted to give a link with http://, but it might not be guaranteed. Why don't you just look for `href` instead?

Example:

```
    <p class="js-tweet-text">
      Blabla tweet text... <a data-expanded-url="http://bit.ly/somelink" 
          class="twitter-timeline-link" href="http://t.co/stuff"
          rel="nofollow" class="twitter-timeline-link">bit.ly/somelink
          </a>
    </p>
```

Here, both `data-expanded-url` and `twitter-timeline-link` seem to give the actual link, while `href` redirects you via some twitter filter. But anyway, one thing you can be certain of is that links contain a `href`.

Comment: please see question edit. Since its not gauranteed safest option is to just scrape the href out the tweet text then ?

Comment: @user470184: It might actually always be formatted with `http://` by Twitter, but I'm not certain. So yes I think looking for href would be somewhat more robust, at least theoretically.